# Familie Singular oder Plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Warum wird die Familie singular dekliniert?

> Meine Familie liebt Pizza.

Warum nicht

> Meine Familie lieben Pizza.

Answer (score 3):

You're asking about *notional agreement of collective nouns*.

"Familie" usually contains multiple people, but grammatically, the word is in singular number. So you use *liebt* and not *lieben*.

In English, looking at meaning instead of grammar is more common than it is in German:

> If the band **are** popular, they will sell lots of records.

However, as Ruby points out in the comments, it's not used for *family*. When exactly it is acceptable to go by notion is unknown to me and a question for an English-speaking forum entirely.

Notional agreement like this does exist in German. For example, you sometimes use a verb in singular when a collocation is the subject:

> Hammer und Meißel ***ist*** das, was wir brauchen.
> Marmor, Stein und Eisen ***bricht***. (A saying)

There can also be a notional agreement when using quantities. In the next example, "Kilogramm" is the head of the phrase and in Singular - because quantities are in Singular - but "Bohnen" in Plural  and "zwei" indicate that we're dealing with a plural in meaning.
Hence we can either use singular or plural for the verb - agreement by meaning or grammar.

> Zwei Kilogramm Bohnen ***reichen*** nicht aus.

For a case like yours, I have never seen notional agreement. Familie is usually used with a verb in singular.

Comment: The English version would be "My family loves Pizza," also singular. I don't want to assume that the person asking the question is fluent in English though. Perhaps in their native language a plural would be more natural, as in "My relatives love pizza."

Comment: @RDBury I don't understand your criticism because I don't see me implying that it would work in English. Maybe I should add a sentence that specifies this.

Comment: I didn't mean to criticize; I was just pointing out that German and English both use a singular noun for the same group (perhaps due to common ancestry). I think "band" could actually go either way and "If the band are popular" sounds very "British" to me

Answer (score 1):

Eine Familie ist eben nur **eine** Gruppe von Menschen. Eine Familie ist **eine** Einheit, auch wenn sie aus mehreren Personen besteht. Ebenso ist ein Paar nur **eine** Gruppe von Menschen. Oder auch eine Fußballmannschaft oder die Belegschaft eines Unternehmens. Sogar die gesamte Menschheit ist nur **eine** Gruppe.

> Das Paar <del>fahren</del> **fährt** mit der Bahn.
> Die Familie <del>wohnen</del> **wohnt** in einem Haus.
> Die Mannschaft <del>nehmen</del> **nimmt** am Turnier teil.
> Die Belegschaft <del>feiern</del> **feiert** das Firmenjubiläum.
> Die Menschheit <del>leben</del> **lebt** auf der Erde.

Erst wenn man von mehreren dieser Gruppen spricht, muss man die Mehrzahl verwenden.

> Die Paare fahren mit der Bahn.
> Die Familien wohnen in Häusern.
> Die Mannschaften nehmen am Turnier teil.

Daher:

- **Eine** Familie = Singular

  > Meine Familie liebt Pizza.
- **Mehrere** Familien = Plural

  > Alle Familien in unserem Dorf lieben Pizza.

Comment: Das ist keine logische Erklärung: _Die Fußballspielerinnen_ ist ja auch eine Gruppe. Und selbst wenn: Die Tatsache, dass es sich um eine Gruppe handelt, reicht als Erklärung nicht aus: Im Englischen etwa wird _the police_ oder _the people_ als Plural angesehen. Das Phänomen kann also nicht allein aus der Semantik abgeleitet werden, sondern es ist eine Eigentümlichkeit der deutschen Grammatik.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: Die Fußballspielerinnen sind mehrere einzelne Personen. Das ist keine Gruppe, daher: Plural. Die Polizisten sind auch einzelne Personen (daher plural) aber die Polizei ist eine Gruppe bzw. eine Einheit und wird daher im Singular verwendet. Wenn in English von *the police* die Rede ist, ist damit selten die Organisation gemeint, so wie im Deutschen, sondern dann sind damit die Polizisten gemeint. Ähnliches gilt für *the people:* Das können *die Leute* sein, also viele einzelne Personen, oder *das Volk,* also eine Gruppe. Die Ursache dafür, dass ...

Comment: ... bei diesen und ähnlichen Begriffen im Englischen eher der Plural und im Deutschen eher der Singular verwendet wird, ist darin zu suchen, dass es im englischen Sprachraum eher üblich ist, die Einzelpersonen zu meinen, die zufällig vielleicht gerade eine Gruppe bilden, während es im deutschen Sprachraum umgekehrt ist: Bei uns meint man vor allem die Gruppe, die als Einheit verstanden wird. Dass diese Gruppe aus mehreren Einzelpersonen besteht, ist im Deutschen von untergeordneter Bedeutung.

Comment: Woher kann man wissen, dass _die Polizistinnen_ keine Gruppe,  sind, _die Polizei_ aber schon, wenn man Deutsch gerade erst lernt? Ich denke, die Antwort auf diese Frage würde deine Antwort viel klarer machen.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: Woher soll man wissen, dass *Urlaub* immer im Singular verwendet wird und *Ferien* immer in Plural? - Das muss man eben lernen. Bei den Polizistinnen ist es sogar ganz leicht: Wenn ein Substantiv, das Personen bezeichnet mit *-innen* endet, dann sind das immer **mehrere** weibliche Personen. Hingegen sind alle Substantive, die auf *-ei* enden, immer singular: Polizei, Datei, Partei, Mahlerei, Bäckerei, Brauerei, Bücherei, Kanzlei, ... - Aber wie gesagt: Das muss man eben lernen.